# How to add a plugin to k9s?

Tags: kubernetes

I want to add the `dive` plugin to k9s.... so I can examine docker images in my cluster.

I know `dive` works for me locally - as in `dive <image:tag>` is fine... however I don't have all images in the service on my workstation

https://github.com/derailed/k9s/tree/master/plugins implies this is easy to do.

I'm running ubuntu, and I've a file called `dive.yml` which is identical to https://github.com/derailed/k9s/blob/master/plugins/dive.yml - except I changed the shortcut to be `b` rather than `d`:

```
plugin:
  dive:
    shortCut: b
    confirm: false
    description: "Dive image"
    scopes:
      - containers
    command: dive
    background: false
    args:
      - $COL-IMAGE
```

I've tried the file in `/etc/xdg/k9s/dive.yml` and `/home/<me>/.config/k9s/dive.yml` - and neither appear to work:

I start k9s; select a pod & hit `<enter>` to list the containers.... highlight the image I want to examine & tap `b` - nothing.

Am I misunderstanding the scope of `dive`?

Do I have it incorrectly configured?

How do I get it to work?

Answer (score 2):

Check the output of `k9s info` command. It will print the expected plugins file location. You should append the plugin definitions to this file.

For those who upgrade to >= 0.30.0 from earlier versions, older config files have `.yml` extension and newer versions expect `.yaml` extension. Move your `plugins.yml` file to `plugins.yaml` You may also want to check the auto generated `config.yaml` contains your `config.yml` changes.

Another thing I found out is that the root of the `plugins.yaml` file was `plugin` for me and it should be changed with `plugins`.

```
 ____  __.________
|    |/ _/   __   \______
|      < \____    /  ___/
|    |  \   /    /\___ \
|____|__ \ /____//____  >
        \/            \/

Version:           v0.31.7
Config:            /home/yusuf/.config/k9s/config.yaml
Custom Views:      /home/yusuf/.config/k9s/views.yaml
Plugins:           /home/yusuf/.config/k9s/plugins.yaml
Hotkeys:           /home/yusuf/.config/k9s/hotkeys.yaml
Aliases:           /home/yusuf/.config/k9s/aliases.yaml
Skins:             /home/yusuf/.config/k9s/skins
Context Configs:   /home/yusuf/.local/share/k9s/clusters
Logs:              /home/yusuf/.local/state/k9s/k9s.log
Benchmarks:        /home/yusuf/.local/state/k9s/benchmarks
ScreenDumps:       /home/yusuf/.local/state/k9s/screen-dumps
```

Comment: I had version 0.27.4 and plugins didn't work. Upgrading to 0.31.9 and changing plugins.yml to plugins.yaml fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Sidenote:

Take care which scope your plugin has. I tried to press the shortcut and nothing worked, because i was in the wrong scope (deployment instead of container)